# Python urllib post request with file payload

Tags: python, post, file-upload, urllib

Does anyone have a urllib recipe in a drawer, on how to make a POST request using [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) exclusively, while combining headers, custom fields and a binary file in the payload?

**Before you continue:** 'urllib2/3', 'requests', 'poster' and other libs are **NOT** available!
The environment is unfortunately massively limited (plugin environment) and stripped of basically everything useful that would make the task easy. Nevertheless we have to get there...

All the examples I've found so far divert to one of the libs above and i wonder if someone has an example ready that he's willing to share?

The below example shows a POST request we're currently working with to send text data only (urlencoded). Including a file will have to switch to multipart/form-data, which is a nuisance without support libs.

```
import urllib.request
url = "https://wwww.target.com/upload/"
values = {
  'param1' : 'value1',
  'param2' : 'value2',
  'param3' : 'value3',
}
postdata = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
postdata = postdata.encode("utf-8")
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=postdata)
req.add_header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
req.add_header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5")
#req.add_header("Cookie", str("; ".join(cookies_tuple)))
req_stream = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
resp_code = req_stream.getcode()
resp = req_stream.read()
req_stream.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after a tip we just got from you guys:

https://pymotw.com/3/urllib.request/#uploading-files
has a class that does exactly what we needed in a very elegant and flexible way.